# Typescript and Jquery syntax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I want to use Jquery in my typescript project. I get issues for code like this:

```
$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
            width: 'auto', 
            height: 'auto', 
            'max-height': '100%'
        });
    });
```

I cannot compile the code, getting errors on myModal part and 'show.bs.modal'. Both of them say 'Parameter declaration expected'. I am new to typescript and I don't know how to make this work. I do have jquery typing file in my project. I work in Visual Studio.

Comment: Add DefinitelyTyped for jQuery to your project - that might help you to understand what's going on, and why.   https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery

Answer (score 0):

You should use JQuery TypeScript Definition.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#readme

[Here](https://bertt.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/typescript-and-jquery-example/) is a walk-through article.